# How to change a text with one dynamic term in all nodes?

Tags: database, 9

I have a core website, no contrib modules or themes are installed.

All my nodes, from several content types, start with the following text, which is written in WYSIWYG CKeditor.

> The term X is used to describe

I wish to change this everywhere to:

> X I describe as

How to change a text with one dynamic term in all nodes?

Comment: There's no "common and safe" way to manipulate field data in the database directly. By definition, you need to use the APIs to get that kind of reliability. The answer depends too much on the format of the data as well, how it's stored, etc.

Comment: What API is the usual for this task? If by format you meant text format than it's the default "Filtered HTML". I don't know the meaning by "how it's stored", I don't have any modules installed, all is core.

Comment: If it was me I'd probably use `hook_post_update_NAME`, batch API and entity API. By format I mean what the data is. If it contains HTML, for example, you really don't want to be using regular expressions to manipulate it, you'd parse it and manipulate it as a `DOMDocument` or whatever before rendering it back to HTML and saving. I'd go so far as to say it would be irresponsible of anyone to advise you on how to do this on your site without doing a proper reccy first

Comment: Why I got so many downvotes?...

Comment: It's totally unclear to me from the documentation what batch API does. https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/batch-api/overview

Comment: The PHP documentation isn't clear to me on how `DOMDocument` can help me. I lack the knowledge to figure this out sadly. https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: I’m afraid that’s not something we can help you with here - if you want to drive you need to learn how to do it first. Same idea here

Comment: Clive I get the metaphor but I have already changed the question to ask how to do it in general, not necessarily with directly manipulating the database in classical SQL. I invite anyone which want to help to construct an answer.

Comment: And by the way I know how to drive, I think, if you meant that I need to learn PHP please just say it. I still hope there is a way to do it without PHP.

Comment: The question should make clear what you tried and what exactly you don't understand in achieving the task. In the case you tried something, the question should also say in which way what you obtained was different from what you expected. If you read Drupal documentation and you don't understand what it says, the question should be explicit about which documentation and what you don't understand. *I don't understand this documentation page.* isn't a sufficient reason to ask a question.

Comment: If you are instead asking the question before reading documentation and before trying to achieve what the question describes, you are asking the question too early.

Comment: The only way to achieve that without writing PHP code is using the user interface. It will take time, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DOMDocument is not going to help here because ultimately this data lives within I assume a formatted text field (WYSIWYG). The best that will do is 'change' the sentence when rendering it, but not actually fix the problem underneath.

Unfortunately this requires one of two paths:

- You manually edit all the content to what you want.
- You run a MySQL Find and Replace query.

The latter is a destructive operation so make a backup before trying anything.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839060/find-and-replace-text-in-the-entire-table-using-a-mysql-query

You are looking for the database table of the field in question (and its revision table too), which is what you will run the query against. Another problem that makes this really difficult is you want to replace a pattern, which requires regular expressions:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace

This is still doable, if not a challenge. You'd need 3 capture groups (regex):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592180/regexp-replace-capturing-groups

The regex may look something like this:

```
(?<subject>The term)\ (?<term>[A-Z0-9]+)\ (?<predicate>is used to describe)
```

Which the replace part *may be*

```
$term I describe as
```

None of this is strictly Drupal related.

In hindsight, this would probably be best solved as a migration plugin against that field where manipulation is a bit easier, safer and iterative than raw SQL queries.

Comment: The 3rd (best IMO) path is to create an update hook, loop over the content, parse the html if needed or just string replace if not, then save it again. If the data contains HTML, don’t consider using a regex

Comment: Yeah, there is that way too, the difficultly in all scenarios is not knowing the variability of the HTML. IMO I would probably replace it with a custom token but thats me. I figured I would go the lengths of explaining why this sort of change is not as easy as it sounds on the surface.

Comment: Yeah, all depends on the structure/complexity of the text data